# Cross tab reports in Logixml

Tags: report

How to add multiple column in cross tab report in logixml,
for example, i can cross tab a sales report by year and salesperson name. but i want to cross tab on the basis of year, month and sales person name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crosstab filter supports building a pivot against a single layer of values from whichever column you choose to represent the crosstab column.  In your described example, if you build your crosstab around the "month" - which would be the lowest level of detail, you could then add a HeaderRow that contains a Crosstab table header Column element.  Inside this, create a label to display years by formatting your @Data.rdCrosstabColumn~ token as a year ('yyyy').

For a more hierarchical or dimensional approach, you could also use the DimensionGrid element to build the type of report you're describing.  If you're using Logi Info, add a DimensionGrid into your report and build a Dimension element for the "time" (eg. Year, Quarter, Month, etc).  For more details on the DimensionGrid, you might find this article helpful as well:

http://www.logixml.com/DevNet/rdPage.aspx?rdReport=Article&dnDocID=1164&Src=2

The DimensionGrid has a data selection menu built into the U/I, so if you're interested in just showing the Table output inside your report, you can optionally hide any of the features that appear as part of this menu.

Regards,
David

Answer (score 0):

This page on LogiXML’s developer network contains all the information (and some more) about how to add multiple columns in crosstab reports.  Have you seen this page before?   http://www.logixml.com/devnet/rdPage.aspx?rdReport=Article&dnDocID=1035&Page=2#ExtraValues.  I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks Will, I have already gone through that link, this link doesn't satisfy my requirement, in the example given on the link, developer add multiple column for different value like in a year they are asking for total sales, total quantity. my requirement is totally different, i need first sales divide on the basis of year then months.